# Cloud server need to push messages to clients behind Router

Tags: php, node.js, redis

We are developing a device for home usage. Every device has its own wifi connected to home router.
Now the problem is that user need to use apps to control these devices outside home, which means that every device must has a long polling connection to my cloud server acting as a bridge. APPs send commands to cloud server, and server redirects commands to clients identified by unique ID associated with devices.
We need to have millions devices sold, which means my cloud server need to have long connections for all of my devices.
I have tried NodeJs with net socket. But during tests, it seems that it could only handle hundreds connections. 
Anyone can explain best architecture for this situation?

Answer (score 1):

Can I recommend you use a web socket such as [SocketIO?](http://socket.io) It sounds like the sort of thing you need, make the client connect to the web socket and await commands, no need for long polling, SocketIO also allows you to control where the data goes with [rooms and namespaces](http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/) and the API is relatively simple to use.

Comment: I really used SocketIO before. But my clients has no browser, they are simply SCM, only can post tcp connect.